# FOR loop:how to get values from a xml page using for loop?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, xml-serialization, simplexml

My xml page:

```
<item>
<title geoid="1198">District of Columbia</title>
<description cong_dist="Delegate District (at Large) 98">DC - Delegate District (at Large) 98 <br/> No of Incidents: 1436</description>
<latitude>38.8933115</latitude>
<longitude>-77.0146475</longitude>
<georss:polygon>38.934311 -77.1199 38.939834989364 -77.112868886998 38.94641 -77.1045 38.94891 -77.1007 38.95651 -77.0915 38.960871062931 -77.085827416011 38.967245703105 -77.077535703105 38.971616050926 -77.07185104194 38.98511 -77.054299 38.986557824794 -77.0523733.885112 -76.919295 38.884412 -76.920195 38.881242218815 -76.92424312618 886998 38.934311 -77.1199</georss:polygon>
</item>
```

i have to take values one by one by the tag<>name in the for loop.

```
for(?){
     geom = items[i].childNodes[j].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

and this values iterated in for loop and i have to store the values in `geom`.

how to take values from the `"sample.xml"` xml page.

and i have to take the values by the `tag name`.

how to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SimpleXMLElement` class of it an loop through the length of the Item you wan to Iterate over

[example and documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php)

i prefer and advice to use foreach